# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 While fatching the data from local json file

Tags: flutter

I have working on my college project that shows information about indian startup.
When I run my app the first time it is showing a red screen error and then after 2 seconds automatically it is loading the screen and display the data.

I tried all possible solution available on google.
Tried solution: [enter link description here](https://fluttercorner.com/rangeerror-index-invalid-value-valid-value-range-is-empty-0/)

> **Error**

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following RangeError was thrown building HomeScreen(dirty, state: _HomeScreenState#2c9da):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  HomeScreen HomeScreen:file:///D:/DE_Project/startupbits/lib/main.dart:17:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:281:36)
#1      _HomeScreenState.build (package:startupbits/screen/homeScreen.dart:35:24)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4870:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4754:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4735:5)
#7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:11)
#8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4729:5)
...     Normal element mounting (171 frames)
#179    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
#180    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6422:36)
#181    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6433:32)
...     Normal element mounting (362 frames)
#543    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
#544    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3540:18)
#545    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1198:16)
#546    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1167:5)
#547    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1112:18)
#548    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2600:19)
#549    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1111:13)
#550    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:944:7)
#551    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:924:7)
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following RangeError was thrown building HomeScreen(dirty, state: _HomeScreenState#2c9da):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  HomeScreen HomeScreen:file:///D:/DE_Project/startupbits/lib/main.dart:17:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:281:36)
#1      _HomeScreenState.build (package:startupbits/screen/homeScreen.dart:35:24)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4870:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4754:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#6      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#7      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#8      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#9      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#10     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#11     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:862:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
====================================================================================================
```

This is the home screen code I called HomeScreen class in main.dart file.

> **HomeScreen.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List _data = [];

  // Fetch content from the json file
  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/StartUpData.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    setState(() {
      if (data != null){
        _data = data;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readJson();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final items = _data[0]["Sector"];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'StartUpBitz',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      body: _data.isNotEmpty
      ? ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items['Food & Beverages'].length != null ? items['Food & Beverages'].length : 0,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
              height: 100,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(items['Food & Beverages'][index]['Companies'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
                  Text('${index}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),)
                ],
              )
          );
        }
      )
      : Center(child: Text("Error"),)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), in your code `readJson` will finish later than the first `build` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**:
In your `HomeScreen`'s `initState()` you have called `readJson()` which is a future function. So, before the execution of `readJson()` is completed the `build()` function is called in which you are accessing `_data`'s first element which does not exist because `readJson()`'s execution is not completed yet.

Once the `readJson()`'s execution is completed, it calls `setState()` which calls the `build()` method again at which point `_data` may have the expected data hence the error goes away after 2 seconds.

---

**Solution 1** (*Recommended*): Use a package like [this screen loader](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_loader) to show loader while you fetch the data

---

**Solution 2**:
Have a flag in your widget like `isReady` which should be `false` initially and when your data is fetched and is valid you can set `isReady` to true. Use this flag to show loader or something in the build function if `isReady` is true else show your widget with the data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the red screen in your case is because this line of code

```
 final items = _data[0]["Sector"];
```

You try to get the first item of the list, but your list is empty `_data = []`,
after calling `readJson()` your `_data` is not empty anymore and the red screen will go.

The structure is not good, is better to use FutureBuilder or...
but t the time you can try

```
final items =_data.isNotEmpty? _data[0]["Sector"]: null ;// or ""
```